# Puppeteer: I can't extract all the elements from <div>

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I have a lot of paragraphs in one  and I am trying to show them in console. Everytime I run the code it finishes, but there is not any text in console.

Here is JS code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeLog() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless:true, 
    defaultViewport:false,
    userDataDir:"./tmp"
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com/console');
  if(page.url() == 'https://example.com/login'){
    await page.type('#input-email', 'example@gmail.com');
    await page.type('#input-password', 'example123');
    await page.click('.button-primary');
    await page.goto('https://example.com/console');
  }

  const pElements = await page.$$('#consoleDiv > div > p:nth-child(n)');
  for (const pElement of pElements) {
    const singleLog = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, pElement);
    console.log(singleLog);
  }

}

scrapeLog();
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<div id="consoleDiv" class="stream card" style="word-break: break-word; overflow: auto scroll;">
 <div class="lines">
      <p data-time="14:51:22"><span class="label label-info">[INFO]</span>
      1SkeLt7 joined the game
      </p>

      <p data-time="14:51:22"><span class="label label-info">[INFO]</span>
      1SkeLt7 joined the game
      </p>

      <p data-time="14:51:22"><span class="label label-info">[INFO]</span>
      1SkeLt7 joined the game
      </p>

      <p data-time="14:51:22"><span class="label label-info">[INFO]</span>
      1SkeLt7 joined the game
      </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add await page.waitForNavigation(); after await page.click('.button-primary'); to wait for navigation.
- Replace const pElements = await page.$$('#consoleDiv > div > p:nth-child(n)'); with const logElements = await page.$$eval('#consoleDiv > div > p', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()));

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeLog() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: null,
    userDataDir: "./tmp"
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com/console');
  if (page.url() === 'https://example.com/login') {
    await page.type('#input-email', 'example@gmail.com');
    await page.type('#input-password', 'example123');
    await page.click('.button-primary');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
  }

  const logElements = await page.$$eval('#consoleDiv > div > p', (elements) =>
    elements.map((el) => el.textContent.trim())
  );

  for (const log of logElements) {
    console.log(log);
  }

  await browser.close();
}

scrapeLog();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is still not showing anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need browser console and not node console, you can try this

```js
    const singleLog = await page.evaluate(el => {
      const result = el.textContent;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }, pElement);
```